# Add amp-experiment variant to links

Tags: amp-html, google-optimize

When running an amp-experiment, I need to include the active variant number to a link. In short, I'm trying to do something like this:

`<a href="https://ampbyexample.com/?v=VARIANT(button-color-experiment)" data-amp-replace="VARIANT">test</a>`

However, the substitution doesn't happen, resulting in `https://ampbyexample.com/?v=VARIANT(button-color-experiment)`.

I'm aware the docs say that only QUERY_PARAM and CLIENT_ID are supported like that, but I was hoping for a lucky break. Is there another way I can include the variant number dynamically?

Comment: why you need to include the variant number as query param?

Comment: @Ben because it will be tracked downstream